# Frame present inside the page shifts to LHS

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am getting this weird issue while executing my script. My script starts filling the value in the form (present inside the frame) and when it reaches the middle of the form, frame presents in the page shifts to left side. can any one explain how to handle it?.[Original form present in the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOufJ.png)

[after moving to the middle of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk93E.png)

Comment: What is the code? Where did you get the error? Which browser/ driver did you experience this?

Comment: Even though the position of the frame is shifted, it should not affect the locators. Can you please share the complete HTML code of the form, and the code you have written so that we can help

Comment: What do you need to handle?  Your images suggest that there was some auto-scrolling happening, but that shouldn't be a problem for Selenium.  Do you see the same behavior if you interact with the page manually?

Comment: kurakura88 - i am facing issue in IE browser.. I am not getting any error actual position of the frame is getting shifted and not affecting any locators

Comment: Breaks Software - This issue is not seen in manual execution only automation scripts creates the problem

Comment: Karthik - Could you suggest some way to share my code and HTML element as an attachment.?